# OnBackPressed doesn't display alert

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, onkeydown, onbackpressed

I tried to override the  **onkeydown()** method along with the **onBackPressed()** method but the alert dialog box doesn't appear instead it just goes back to the previous intent.I tried a several examples but none of them worked.

```
 @Override
     public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
          if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        onBackPressed();

      }

      return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }

      @Override
       public void onBackPressed() {


       Log.d("confirm save method","");
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

           builder.setTitle("");
           builder.setMessage("Do you want to Save the Game ?");
           builder.setCancelable(false);
               builder.setPositiveButton("YES",
                 new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });

    builder.setNegativeButton("NO",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

               AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
              alert.show();


            Log.d("confirm save method","");
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
            .setTitle("Exit Alert")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    //finishAffinity(); 
                    finish();  //or do anything
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

try this code, and also remove your onKeyDown();

Answer (score 1):

- Tip1: if you override `onBackPressed`,you do not have to override `onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)`. That is complicated. delete this method(`onKeyDown`) can solve this issue.
- Tip2:`return true` to interrupt this key event.

  ```
   @Override
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        alertAialog();
        return true;
        }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }
  private void alertDialog(){
   ...
  }
  ```